# How can I decode the log data using Python

Tags: web3.py, python

I have this log here:

```
{'removed': False, 'logIndex': '0x1b', 'transactionIndex': '0x7', 'transactionHash': '0x40f36c257d1298b85f924faf42de44f46a17b96037a12e798b066c12d49eebb7', 'blockHash': '0xb85ebe68112a0ebb2024df7263e95a5881970def9ea72806eb2687c943f7af50', 'blockNumber': '0xf1adb4', 'address': '0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640', 'data': '0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0480faaf40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025c2cc26741a4db5a000000000000000000000000000000000000632cf6956757b0df7448e1e67d170000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011eebf3c7c54531e30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031863', 'topics': ['0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67', '0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45', '0x0000000000000000000000005aaaef91f93be4de932b8e7324abbf9f26daa706']}
```

I would like to decode the data key

```
'data': '0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0480faaf40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025c2cc26741a4db5a000000000000000000000000000000000000632cf6956757b0df7448e1e67d170000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011eebf3c7c54531e30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031863'
```

I know that somehow I need to use the contract ABI to do this. Does someone have any idea on how to do it?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Contract event objects to decode the transaction receipt with [processReceipt](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/contracts.html?highlight=processreceipt#web3.contract.ContractEvents).

```py
    # Decode the last output.
    # Assume Swap events go in the same chain as path
    swap = pair.events.Swap()

    # The tranasction logs are likely to contain several events like Transfer,
    # Sync, etc. We are only interested in Swap events.
    events = swap.processReceipt(tx_receipt, errors=DISCARD)

    # (AttributeDict({'args': AttributeDict({'sender': '0xDe09E74d4888
```

[See full example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/eth_defi/uniswap_v2/analysis.py#L174).

Note that logs are in the transaction receipt (output), not in the transaction (input).